# Parse object in an array with Node.js

Tags: arrays, json, node.js, parsing, object

I receive a json code from a database with an object into an array.
I don't find how to parse this code.
This is the json code :

```
[ { name: 'John1', surname: 'Doe1' },
  { name: 'John2', surname: 'Doe2' },
  { name: 'John3', surname: 'Doe3' },
  { name: 'John4', surname: 'Doe4' } ]
```

I want to get the name and the surname.

Comment: i think you need to clear basic JavaScript concept first. These are very basic lopping concepts

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = [ { name: 'John1', surname: 'Doe1' },
  { name: 'John2', surname: 'Doe2' },
  { name: 'John3', surname: 'Doe3' },
  { name: 'John4', surname: 'Doe4' } ]

for(i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
    console.log(arr[i].name);
    console.log(arr[i].surname);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Store it in a variable. It's an array of `JSON`.

```
var foo = [ { name: 'John1', surname: 'Doe1' },
            { name: 'John2', surname: 'Doe2' },
            { name: 'John3', surname: 'Doe3' },
            { name: 'John4', surname: 'Doe4' } ]
```

`foo[0]` is `{ name: 'John1', surname: 'Doe1' }`

Now, `foo[0].name`, `foo[0].surname` can be used to access the value pairs.

To do this in a better way, use `loops`

Hope this helps.

Comment: @MatL Glad to help. kawadhiya21's answer is also correct, but I wanted to point you in the right direction, as I believe that you have just started learning `node.js`. Please mark the answer as accepted, if you found it helpful.

Comment: @MatL i think you need to clear basic JavaScript concept first. These are very basic lopping concepts.

Answer (score 0):

So, you need to use a for loop for this and have to iterate through each element.

Here is  how you can do this:
First assign your array into a variable named userData.

```
var userData = [ { name: 'John1', surname: 'Doe1' },
  { name: 'John2', surname: 'Doe2' },
  { name: 'John3', surname: 'Doe3' },
  { name: 'John4', surname: 'Doe4' }]
```

Now loop over your array userData:

```
for(i=0; i < userData.length; i++) {
    console.log(userData[i].name + ' ' + userData[i].surname);
}
```

The output will be like this:

```
John1 Doe1
John2 Doe2
John3 Doe3
John4 Doe4
```